# Get file name from package folder in the External Storage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my App i download the different extensions of file with android download manager class .

> This is download manager code (in the onBindviewHolder) :

```
 //=============BTN DOWNLOAD CLICK LISTENER =========================

        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink()));

                request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                request.setDescription("Downloading ...");
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(), "downloaded", questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownFileName());
                long enqueueId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
```

As you can see in code ,I save the file in External storage .

> Android > data > my package name > files > downloaded

Know my question is how can i get file name in this path and show theme in RecyclerView ?